# how to, best way to use a linear actuator vs gear system?

Tags: pullup, manufacturing, actuator

I am wondering what is the best and cheap option to use in a crane like system.

a linear actuator or a gear rig system with an engine.

the weight at the end could be up to 100 pounds.

I was thinking about using a linear actuator, but I'm worried that the angle might not be enough to push the payload up if i wanted to

in the image below the vertical part can be moved up or down

[image: iamge]

Comment: This is a mechanical question, as opposed to EE question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully obvious from your diagram how the two shown systems are intended to work, and the question is largely **but not fully** a mechanical one that risks being closed.

However, what you are trying to achieve is clear enough and I believe that the clear answer is that a geared motor is liable to be your best choice in most cases, because ...

"Linear actuator" is an inexact term and may mean a self contained unit which essentially IS a geared motor driving an extending rod, or a linear motor, or a solenoid or perhaps a pneumatic or hydraulic cylinder, or thermally expanded or phase changed material, or ...?
[Here are some examples of what people mean by the term "linear actuator"](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=1031&q=%22linear+actuator%22&oq=%22linear+actuator%22&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2590.7832.0.8128.17.17.0.0.0.0.234.3166.3j0j14.17.0....0...1ac.1.32.img..3.14.2541.Rjsigck3zlo) and here are some examples of what are described by ["electric linear actuator"](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=%22electric+linear+actuator%22&spell=1&sa=X&ei=-2jGUp3WBonGkgWI3IAY&ved=0CEsQBSgA&biw=1920&bih=1031&dpr=1). You'll note a very large % contain a rotary motion electric  motor and some form of rotary to linear converter.
ie An 'ELA' ("electric linear actuator") is most often a motor plus gearbox system that has been predesigned and packaged to meet an envisaged need or to suit a range of applications.

While an ELA can be used in a wide range of "crane" type operations it is not suitable in most general cases. This is because an ELA has predefined and limited stroke and does not lend itself to ease of application of its application at some other point without use of additional parts.

Generally the terms "cheap", "up to 100 pounds load" and ELA do not go together if you are using commercially manufactured equipment.

By building what you want with material that is cheap or free and that overall meets your need you will be able to meet a wider range of requirements at far lower prices than could be achieved with an ELA. Effectively you are constructing an ELA from component parts, with the added benefit tjat the ELA can be "distributed" as it does not come as a packaged unit. A "crane" which eg has a motor at its base, a boom arm with a load lifting hook several pulleys and a rope or drive belt to transfer power, constitutes an ELA that extends from the motor, up the tower, along the boom and down the "rope" to the hook.

You have not said how fast or how far you want the load moved.
I'll use metric units here as they has a nice relationship between distance moved, force, time and power required, but you can convert to steam-driven units if required.
Mass: 1 kg = 1 kilogram ~= 2.2 pounds mass.
Distance: 1 m = 1 metre ~= 3.28 feet. (1 foot = 0.3048m exactly)
Force: 1 Newton = 0.1 kg "close enough"
   (Force = g x mass.   )
( g = acceleration due to gravity - g = 9.80665 m/s/s exactly ~+ 10)
Power: Watts = Force x distance = mass x g x distance

SO ...

Power = mass x distance/second x g
Power ~= kg x metres_moved_per_second x 10

.... P = M x D x 10

Example: Say load is 50 kg =~ 110 pounds.

To move 50 kg vertically at 1 ms requires Power = MxDx10 = 50 x 1 x 10 = 500 Watts.
To lift 50kg at 10 m/s requires 5000 Watts.
To ift 50 kg a 10mm = 1cm = 0/01m per second requires 5 Watts.
The above Watts are the actual power used to move a suspecned load vertically. Inefficiencies in motors, gearboxes, pulleys, lever systems etc aqnd forces applied in other than required directions, will lead to higher power being needed.
BUT the aqbove gives an idea of what is required.
If you want "as cheaply as possible" then a say 10 Watt motor will "winch up" a 50 kg weight at about 10 mm per second. 
If you have 100 or 1000 or 10,000 Watts available you can winch the same load at 100mm/s or 1m/s or 10 m/s. More power needs more attention to cables, booms and construction in general. BUT a 50 kg load is not a trivial load and needs care with even a 10 Watt winch motor. **A 50 kg load on a crane can easily kill someone.**

Some of the ways of making you own distributed ELA / crane system include, motor with:

- Gearbox - gears, worm and gear(s), pulleys, ...
- Rope, wire-rope, belt (flat / V / toothed,...)
- Levers (as per your diagram)
- Threaded rod with "captive nut" - turn rod and nut climbs the rod.
- ...

Real world low cost solutions:

- Battery drills. I'm doing exactly this at present for a project - A cheap easy fun and effective system can be made using old electric battery-operated drills driving a rotating threaded rod with a captive nut acting as a linear drive point. A typical 12V or 18V electric drill driving a 10mm diameter, 1mm pitch threaded rod will lift about 100kg at around the 20mm/second rate.
  Power  100 x 0.020 x 10 = 20 Watts.
  Real power will be higher but at 18V load current at about 80 kg load is under 2A.
  2 metres of  1mm pitch threaded 10mm dia galvanised rod can be bought here for under $10. Well used but usefully functional battery electric drills are close to free (the batteries usually die first).
- Depending on load and speed requirements a used car wiper motor may provide a useful solution. Car wipers cycle at about 1 to 2 cycles per second. Some mechanisms make only a to and from motion available while others have output shafts that turn at 60 to 120 RPM. Power levels are generally lower than that which can be obtained from larger battery electric drills. (Ask me how I know :-) ).
- Motor gearbox units made for wheelchair drives and similar are often rated in the 200W - 500 W range and are robust enough for frequent use in crane applications - but are also usually not overly low cost.

Ask for additional information if desired.